# Error while testing destroy-method for a Spring bean using TestNG

Tags: java, spring, testng

I am trying to test init-method and destroy-method for a Spring bean with a simple code implementation. The configuration file has the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- chapter4/src/test/resources/config-03.xml -->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean name="foo"
      class="com.bsg5.chapter4.ThirdObject"
      init-method="init"
      destroy-method="dispose"
  />
</beans>
```

The code to test the methods is the following:

```
package com.bsg5.chapter4;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

class ThirdObject extends HasData {
    static Object semaphore = null;

    public void init() {
        semaphore = new Object();
    }

    public void dispose() {
        semaphore = null;
    }
}

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/config-03.xml")
public class TestLifecycle03 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void testInitDestroyMethods() {
        assertNotNull(context);
        ThirdObject o1 = context.getBean(ThirdObject.class);
        assertNotNull(ThirdObject.semaphore);
        assertEquals(o1.getDatum(), "default");
        context.close();
        assertNull(ThirdObject.semaphore);
    }
}
```

I am attaching the code, [beginning-spring-5](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8x9jy1fmdymn8vx/AACW-PZamnp-r-6g8odVu1gsa?dl=0).
I get 3 errors on executing

gradle chapter4:test

I am showing 1 error.
springTestContextAfterTestClass

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext loaded for [[MergedContextConfiguration@30c604d2 testClass = TestLifecycle03, locations = '{classpath:/config-03.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[[empty]], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]] is not active. This may be due to one of the following reasons: 1) the context was closed programmatically by user code; 2) the context was closed during parallel test execution either according to @DirtiesContext semantics or due to automatic eviction from the ContextCache due to a maximum cache size policy.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:97)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.publishEvent(TestContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener.afterTestClass(EventPublishingTestExecutionListener.java:147)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestClass(TestContextManager.java:488)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextAfterTestClass(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:225)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:61)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:366)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:320)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:217)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:130)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:141)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:90)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

If I remove context.close(), the errors go away, but I am unable to test destroy-method.